# Perform an integration over the unit interval of a two-parameter expression involving a Gauss hypergeometric function

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, mp.mathematical-physics, integration, special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

In a quantum-information-theoretic context, I've encountered the problem
of integrating over $r \in [0,1]$, the function

\begin{equation}
r^{2 d-1} \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{d}{2},\frac{d}{2};\frac{d+2}{2};r^2\right)
   \left(1-\varepsilon ^2 r^2\right)^{d/2},
\end{equation}

where the parameters $d \geq 1$ and $0<\varepsilon<1$. Mathematica does not appear to directly succeed with this problem. I have tried using certain Pfaff transformations in this regard.

For fixed even values of $d$, the integration yields a polynomial of degree $ d$ in $\varepsilon$, while for odd values of $d$, the integration, quite differently, yields results involving inverse hyperbolic and polylogarithmic functions of $\varepsilon$.

The question pertains to the problem of constructing the functions $\tilde{\chi}_d (\varepsilon)$, raised in https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.01410 and further studied in https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.01973, concerning certain conjectures as to the (rational) values of `generalized two-qubit Hilbert-Schmidt separability probabilities''. ($\varepsilon$ is the`singular value ratio'' and $d$ is a ``Dyson-index-like'' parameter, associated with random matrix theory.)

If we set $\varepsilon=0$, then the  requested  integration yields
\begin{equation}
\frac{\, _3F_2\left(-\frac{d}{2},\frac{d}{2},d;1+\frac{2}{d},d+1;1\right)}{2 d},
\end{equation}
while if we set $\varepsilon=1$, then we obtain
\begin{equation}
\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{d}{2}+1\right) \Gamma (d) \,
   _3F_2\left(-\frac{d}{2},\frac{d}{2},d;1+\frac{2}{d},\frac{3 d}{2}+1;1\right)}{2 \Gamma
   \left(\frac{3 d}{2}+1\right)}.
\end{equation}
So, we want a function $f(\varepsilon,d)$ that, in some sense, interpolates between these two endpoints, yielding those polynomials (as indicated by Carlo Beenakker) that result from the integration for even $d$, such as 
\begin{equation}
f(\varepsilon,4)=\frac{13 \varepsilon ^4}{672}-\frac{31 \varepsilon ^2}{630}+\frac{1}{30}.
\end{equation}

Comment: for even $d$ the hypergeometric function is just a polynomial and the integral can be evaluated in closed form.

Comment: Thanks, Carlo Beenakker. The integral can apparently be evaluated in closed form for any specific $d>0$, even or odd--being much simpler (as noted) in the even case. But, I was wondering if the integral could be evaluated/expressed in some form as both a function of the parameters $d$ and $\varepsilon$. This might allow me to pursue some further analyses of potential interest.

Comment: Dr. Slater, I was reading your paper "Master Lovas-Andai and Equivalent Formulas Verifying the $\frac{8}{33}$ Two-Qubit Hilbert-Schmidt Separability Probability and Companion Rational-Valued Conjectures" and noted a link to here. Along with our websites math.SE we also have a [Quantum Computing](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/) site which I noticed you are not a member of, and I invite you to join. YT

Answer (score 1):

An integration-by-parts yielded the result
\begin{equation}
-\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{d}{2}+1\right)^2 \Gamma (d) \left(\Gamma (d+1)^2 \,
   _3\tilde{F}_2\left(-\frac{d}{2},\frac{d}{2},d;\frac{d}{2}+1,\frac{3
   d}{2}+1;\varepsilon ^2\right)-2 \,
   _2F_1\left(-\frac{d}{2},\frac{d}{2};\frac{d+2}{2};\varepsilon ^2\right)\right)}{2
   \Gamma (d+1)^2}.
\end{equation}

Added together with a set of auxiliary results, this leads to a formula for the "Lovas-Andai function" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.01410)
\begin{equation}
\tilde{\chi}_d (\varepsilon )=\frac{\varepsilon ^d \Gamma (d+1)^3 \,
   _3\tilde{F}_2\left(-\frac{d}{2},\frac{d}{2},d;\frac{d}{2}+1,\frac{3
   d}{2}+1;\varepsilon ^2\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{d}{2}+1\right)^2},
\end{equation}
where the tilde is used to denote the regularized hypergeometric function.